# Link Dynamic URL to div in Umbraco

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, umbraco

I am building a site using Umbraco and I have a div that currently has a link inside it. The current code is:

```
<div class="callout col-sm-4 leftCtaLink">
    <p>@CurrentPage.leftDescription</p>
    <a class="primary-bg" href="@CurrentPage.leftCtaLink"><img class="svg-inject" src="@Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.leftIcon).umbracoFile" alt="Icon" />@CurrentPage.leftCtaText</a>
</div>
```

This works and only the bottom half of the callout links to the correct page. The client wants the whole div to be linkable now though, so I thought I'd do this with jQuery. Here is that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".leftCtaLink").click( function() {
        window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("@CurrentPage.leftCtaLink");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

The issue is, that when the div is clicked on, it takes me to the website's url with /undefined at the end of it. Can anyone tell me what I need to change in the JS to have it use the correct URL that was input in the CMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to `attr("href")`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".leftCtaLink").click( function() {
        window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: That's it! I understand how that works now. I am not very good with jQuery. But DUH! It's searching for the link inside the div and making the whole div link there. Makes perfect sense. Thank you! I will mark resolved as soon as it lets me.

Comment: I'm glad I could you! Have a nice day.

Comment: I don't log in often enough to have caught this till now. Sorry about that. It's marked resolved now.